# Docker-compose assigns non coherent IPs for my containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have several containers on my server, and almost using the same docker-composer.yaml file :

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:

    myAppX:
        container_name: myprojectX
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile
        env_file: .env
        ports:
            - 8009:80
        volumes:
            - ${DIR_IMAGES_MAPS}:/app/public/maps
```

I've notice the containers don't always have the same IP :

```bash
docker inspect -f '{{.Id}};{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -q)

696fa33040be3c13f03e7f7697450d753dcb87aeff8629b2418b17a2b3d0baff;192.168.96.2
49ab637898ecb79e5b18a22e6d9466ab6f712960695046ba0c233437475cad3d;192.168.32.2
ba9912bb221b53f7b319430f1624a17a8d25ababb68854717e88026e448539fc;172.26.0.2
b21ad6f8bd9770de20edf55a07e3e2531d4a5d67f2cc15749146c16f27400263;172.25.0.2
4bb3b317e22fa96cef5e219a81909052a899fbc1a48401c63f292050ab3734a7;172.23.0.2
74df8ec521bbe08fcfc3851558349add7c4bead2314ee49e63f80a63d67420c6;172.22.0.2
35bbfe5d3e52a4b2ae5907e815a4cdbd0b7c4cd5ac21c348c8aa65d078ea892f;172.21.0.3
0f0ad718b5110f6ce8c4bd44a931f9ad10fc48d485bda9d6708767cf9ba486e9;172.21.0.4
5c590d55a128e69b256a92bff703c112db6f4bc9f2bbdb6c503f40afa24395d2;172.21.0.2
006269c383d5a424ba123abc1d54e802bf297542f623b6925002cbc365c16d85;172.20.0.2
5d13ed8352c833d18ee16aa7b9fec2604c600032bdcd8d10d9c94ea0faaca539;172.19.0.2
```

I don't get why the two first containers have an IP with 192. and not like the other with 172. ! All my containers have to use the same IP (172.) due to firewall rules ! But with Composer v3 I can no more define static IP !

How can I force docker to always have the same IP type ?

Comment: It looks like you have containers on multiple docker networks. Docker selects a new address range for reach network. It seems unlikely that the container address should conflict with your firewall rules (because these addresses are never seen on the network), but if you want you can [limit the address pools that docker uses for networks](https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit (or create) `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add this :

```
{
  "bip":"172.17.0.1/16"
}
```

Then restart docker service.

IP ends with 1 and not 0 ! Maybe Docker don't want a mask but he need the very first IP !